# populating 2d array with two 1d arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have 2 1d arrays and im trying to populate them into a single 2d array in JAVA.

For instance:

```
x[] = {2,5,7,9}
y[] = {11,22,33,44}
```

The results should then be:

```
result[][] = {{2,5,7,9}, {11,22,33,44}}
```

How do I go about this? I currently have something like this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col == y.length; col++) {
        ???
    }
}
```

Im sort of stuck from there...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

2D array is an array of arrays. So why don't you try  this?

```
int result[][] = {x,y};
```

And to make sure that it is so simple and works, test this:

```
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<result[0].length; j++)
        System.out.print(result[i][j]+ " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: :) Why people are giving other answers. +1 for this one.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

tempList.add(x);
tempList.add(y);

Integer result[][] = new Integer[tempList.size()][];
result = tempList.toArray(tempList);
```

Comment: the arraylist is just a temporary container for the arrays. you can add multiple arrays of different sizes to the arraylist and get the corresponding 2D-array from it afterwards using toArray().
but the answer of deporter is clearly simpler if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to revert the row and column indices

```
for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0; col = y.length; col++)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```