# How to convert Object[] to Object[][]

Tags: java, object, vector

Basic Java question: 
I have a one dimensional Object, converted from a vector:

```
Vector<Combination> allValues = getAllValues();  
Object[] combinations = allValues.toArray();
```

Entry `combination[n]` consists of several integer values like *{0,0,0,0}*.

I want to create a two dimensional **Object 4xN** (`Object[][]`) that i can reach every integer value.

What is the nicest way to create a two dimensional `Object` from a one dimensional one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324380/populating-2d-array-with-two-1d-arrays-in-java

Comment: Um...you go through the `Combination` objects one by one and convert _those_ to arrays?

Comment: I need to deliver a object[][] to another function (Unit Test for more Values: TestNG). The Question of assylias does not suite for my problem. i have just one object[]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could of course create an vector of arrays...which is rather ugly. Better thing would be to just keep your 1D Index and compute the indices with offset..

The real question is: What does your data look like; Why do you want 2D indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Object[] from each Combination object. Does the combination class have a toArrays() method? If so then you're done. if not then you will have to define one yourself, or if you don't have access to its source, create an Object[] and manually add the values from each combination object.

Comment: This is unambiguously the right answer, although I'm out of upvotes for the day.